# CouchDB 3rd Party Login / Signup (Facebook, Twitter, etc)

Tags: oauth, couchdb, cloudant, couchapp

I am faced with an issue in how to implement **3rd Party Login** with **CouchDB**.

Currently as I know, CouchDB provides its own Member System, and has several **Authentication Methods, Cookie, Oauth, Prox**y etc.

I figured that using **http_auth_proxy** plugin in CouchDB, might do the trick, but as it seems in **CouchDB 2.0**, there is a bug and its (for now) impossible to enable **http_auth_proxy**.

Now, I've done some research, but still can't wrap my head around the 3rd party login, and how to achieve this with CouchDB.

What I specifically want to do is as following:

1. Authenticate (Login/Signup) through the default CouchDB member system
2. Authenticate (Login/Signup) with 3rd party networks (Facebook, Twitter etc.)
3. Both of these systems of authentication should have the same user base, and if a user who signed up through the 1st method and now tries to auth with the 2nd method, if the email is similar, simply authenticates and appends the access_tokens (authentication details)

Would pretty much appreciate if someone has faced with this problem, and found a solution. If they could describe how they managed to solve it.

Comment: It's been a couple of months - did you find an solution?

Comment: @vishvAsvAsuki, so the problem lied with CouchDB Proxy, and several major bugs on CouchDB! So for now there's no solution, until the guys at CouchDB fix the issues.

Comment: Is this still the case?